# SharedPreferences reverted to a previous state

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreferences` to maintain a sequence number of requests sent to my backend from my android app. Each android device maintains the sequence locally, in `SharedPreferences`, and increment the sequence whenever a new request is sent to the backend.

Following is the sequence number generation logic.

```
private static String getNextRequestId() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ApplicationEx.getContext());
    long sequenceNumber = sharedPreferences.getLong(SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 0);
    boolean committed = sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(SEQUENCE_NUMBER, sequenceNumber + 1).commit();
    if (!committed) {
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    }
    return String.valueOf(sequenceNumber);
}
```

In rare occasions, I have observed that some devices have sent a sequence number which it already had sent previously. For an example, a device sends requests with sequence numbers upto 100, and it starts sending sequence numbers starting from 50 again.

The only scenario I can think of as the cause is that SharedPreferences have been re-set to a previous value.

Does anyone know whether there is a possibility of SharedPreferences to reset to a previous value automatically? Or any other way which explains this behavior?

Comment: There might be a chance where user cleared the app's storage/cache which basically wipes out the SharedPreference values stored.

Comment: If user cleared data, sequence should go to zero. But it doesn't go all the way to zero, but to a middle value. When user cleared data, a re-login is required, where the sequence is set to the last seen value of the backend.